# structure circuliar depenency

Tags: c++, struct, circular-dependency

I have two structs:

```
struct B;
struct A {
    B *b;
    void Func() {
        std::cout << b->x << std::endl;
    }
};
struct B {
    A a;
    float x;
    void Func() {
        a.Func();
    }
};
```

When I try to compile this, I get following errors:

```
Error C2027 use of undefined type 'B'
Error C2227 left of '->x' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by moving the definition of `Func` outside of the class declaration to a point where `B` is fully defined, e.g.:

```
struct B;
struct A {
    B *b;
    // Only declare Func, do not provide definition
    void Func();
};
struct B {
    A a;
    float x;
    void Func() {
        a.Func();
    }
};

// Define Func where the full definition of B is available
void A::Func() {
    std::cout << b->x << std::endl;
}
```